# Why doesn't the google search API show images?

Tags: javascript, google-search-api

When I use the google search api example from [here](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/)

It doesn't show me any results for Images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Hello World - Google  Web Search API Sample</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //<!
    google.load('search', '1');

    function OnLoad() {
      // Create a search control
      var searchControl = new google.search.SearchControl();

      // Add in a full set of searchers
      var localSearch = new google.search.LocalSearch();
      searchControl.addSearcher(localSearch);
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.VideoSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.BlogSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.NewsSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.ImageSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.BookSearch());
      searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.PatentSearch());

      // Set the Local Search center point
      localSearch.setCenterPoint("New York, NY");

      // tell the searcher to draw itself and tell it where to attach
      searchControl.draw(document.getElementById("searchcontrol"));

      // execute an inital search
      searchControl.execute("VW GTI");
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);

    //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="searchcontrol">Loading</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The option is there through this line

```
searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.ImageSearch());
```

However the results say `0`. 
Shouldn't there be at least a couple of images? I think a couple of weeks ago when I tried it, it still worked?

Any idea?

Comment: Can you include your full code of how you're invoking the API and inspecting the results?

Comment: *Why doesn't* `not` *why does ... not*

Comment: @HappyCoding thanks!